# Opendaylight Oxygen mounted resources api's are undefined

Tags: java, opendaylight, ietf-netconf

I am using Opendaylight Oxygen version. I am connecting a Netconf device using the odl-netconf-clustered-topology feature as described in the [Netconf User Guide](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/user-guide/netconf-user-guide.html)

The device is successfully connected, which I confirmed by viewing the connection status in the network-topology api. 
I tried to configure the device data using the Mounted Resources section of the Restconf page. But the api's of the device yang are not accessible. The Restconf URL's are shown as undefined.

When I tried the same steps in the previous versions (ie) Boron,Carbon and Nitrogen, it worked perfectly fine.

I contacted the netconf-dev mailing list and they told me to raise a bug request in jira. Before doing that, I wanted to ask if anyone else has faced the same issue and have overcome it.

Environment details:

```
Java version - 1.8.0_161
OS - Ubuntu 16.04
Opendaylight version - Oxygen SR1
Features installed: 

    odl-netconf-topology
    odl-restconf-all
```